# Google Apps Script Sheet: how to create a Ui Prompt that only shows if the condition is met

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

the code below is part of a larger script used for scheduling events on Google Calendar based on Google Sheets. The script goes through available data on spreadsheet and schedules events based on them. If the value in column D is "Yes" a recurring event should be scheduled otherwise a normal event. I have omitted the Apps Script methods for scheduling events from here.

The user clicks a menu button and runs the script.

I want the user to see a prompt if there are any "Yes" values in column D, and then use the user input to schedule that recurring event.

When I try to run this script from the dedicated menu on Google Sheets I receive an error "Exception: Argument cannot be null: buttons".

[image]

Ui Code here

```
function onOpen() {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui
    .createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
    .addItem('Add selected events', 'calendarAdd')
    .addToUi();
}

function recurEventPrompt() {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let userInput = ui.prompt('Schedule Recurring Event', 'Please enter event duration', ui.ButtonSet.Daily_Weekly);
  return userInput;
}
```

Script here

```
function calendarAdd() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let eventSheet = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet();
  let activeCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('Calendar ID');
  let eventArray = eventSheet.getRange(2, 1, eventSheet.getMaxRows(), eventSheet.getMaxColumns());
  let eventValues = eventArray.getDisplayValues().filter(x => x[0] != '');

  for (e of eventValues) { 
    let eventName = e[0];;
    let startTime = new Date(e[1]);
    let endTime = new Date(e[2]);
    let recurring = e[3];

    if (recurring === 'Yes') { /* here I need to have the script show the prompt only if 
the value in corresponding column in 'Yes', otherwise the prompt should not be shown.*/
      response = recurEventPrompt();
      console.log(`user selected ${response.getSelectedButton()}`);
        if (response.getSelectedButton() == 'Daily') //schedule daily event;
          console.log('daily event scheduled');
        else if (response.getSelectedButton() == 'Weekly') //schedule weekly event;
          console.log('weekly event scheduled');
    }
    else // create a regular event;
      console.log ('regular event scheduled');
  } 
}
```

Comment: You could have `ui.prompt("Schedule Recurring Event. Please enter event duration (Yes=Daily, No=Weekly)",ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO)` where Yes is Daily and No is Weekly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the last parameter of your `ui.prompt()`, the only available values you can input are:

- **OK**   Enum    A single "OK" button, indicating an informational message that can only be dismissed.
- **OK_CANCEL**    Enum    An "OK" button and a "Cancel" button, allowing the user to either proceed with or halt an operation.
- **YES_NO**   Enum    A "Yes" button and a "No" button, allowing the user to answer a yes/no question.
- **YES_NO_CANCEL**    Enum    A "Yes" button, a "No" button, and a "Cancel" button, allowing the user to either answer a yes/no question or halt an operation.

If you need to use have custom buttons, you have to use [Custom Dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs).

### Example:

Here I created a custom dialog that has 2 buttons, **Daily** and **Weekly**, it will run a function named `myFunction()` in html that will run `print()` function in Apps Script.

**Code.gs:**

```
function recurEventPrompt() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Dialog')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Schedule Recurring Event');
}

function print(a){
  Logger.log(a);
}
```

**Dialog.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      Please enter event duration
      <br><br>
      <input type="text" id="duration" name="duration">
      <br><br>
      <button id='daily'>Daily</button>
      <button id='weekly'>Weekly</button>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
      function myFunction(){
        var type = this.id // the value of this is either daily/weekly)
        google.script.run.print()(type);
      }
      document.getElementById('daily').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
      document.getElementById('weekly').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
  </script>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Since this method calls a function instead of returning value to the caller, you need to replace the `print()` function in my code with another function that will handle this part of your code:

```
if (response.getSelectedButton() == 'Daily') //schedule daily event;
  console.log('daily event scheduled');
else if (response.getSelectedButton() == 'Weekly') //schedule weekly event;
  console.log('weekly event scheduled');
```

### Reference:

- [ButtonSet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button-set)
- [prompt(title, prompt, buttons)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#prompt(String,String,ButtonSet))

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. I worked on implementing it but I ran into a problem. Seems like the execution is complete after showing the prompt, so regardless of what function I want to assign to those buttons, it is not possible to capture the values and use them anywhere else. Any solutions for this?

Comment: @Ari - By design custom dialog can only run functions unlike the usual dialog where it waits the user input before proceeding to another line of code. I also noticed that you want the dialog to prompt for every loop, In that case custom dialog wont work. But there are 2 possible solutions to this, to use inputbox where you have to type the duration and the daily/weekly manually and parse it or a sidebar where it has the same  UI as custom dialog but instead it moves the active range to the next row when you click the daily/weekly buttons rather than prompting it multiple times.